# Pure CSS way to unhide a drop-down menu (or any HTML element) when a certain option in a preceding drop-down menu is selected

Tags: html, css

Server-side dev here, dabbling in a bit of CSS.

I'm trying to use a `selected` option within a drop-down menu to display another drop-down. Whilst there are several publicly available JS solutions to such a problem, the challenge here is to do it purely in CSS, without any JS help.

Currently, I've tried to write CSS that adds `display:block` to a hidden element (a `select` element) when `option` with `value="1"` is `selected` within a preceding `select` element.

Needless to say it hasn't worked. It would be great to get expert opinion on how to accomplish this sort of a thing (with an illustrative example).

On the other hand, if it's not possible, it would be great to get an illustrative example of an alternative CSS-only solution to the problem (if it exists).

---

**What I'm trying:**

```css
body{
   background: #f0f3f4
}

.second{
   display:none
}
   
select#first option[value="1"]:selected ~ .second{
   display: block
}
```

```html
<select id="first" style="width:95%;padding:6px 0;border:1px solid #3cb7dd;border-radius:5px;text-align:center;color:#1f8cad" class="cm mt sp mbl" name="turl">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Selector 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
    
<div class="second">
<select style="width:95%;padding:6px 0;border:1px solid #3cb7dd;border-radius:5px;text-align:center;color:#1f8cad" class="cm mt sp mbl" name="turl">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Selector 2</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

p.s. browser-compatibility is a consideration, so it would be great if a suggested solution adheres to well-supported CSS/HTML.

Comment: there is no `:selected` pseudo class but `:checked`

Comment: @TemaniAfif: that implies it's impossible to do this via a `selected` option from a drop-down (i.e. `select` element)?

Comment: The only way to do this with css only would be to use radios instead of a select for the first list

Comment: Short answer: no it's impossible with your actual setting but we may find a *hacky* way by simulating a select differently using your own code and not the native one

Comment: @temaniafif: could you shed some illustrative light on the said *hacky way* in an answer? I suppose if that's the best I've got, I'll select it as the correct solution given this particular question's unique circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you could use and abuse anchors and :target selector. [Something like this](https://jsbin.com/gopedafopa/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @villekoo: pardon me but isn't relying on `onchange="location=this.value;"` revoking the CSS-only requirement?

Comment: I said *we my find*. Actually I don't have something in mind but if you create a custom select using CSS you will probably have more luck to be able to do what you want since you can adjust the HTML code as needed. The other difficult part is how to create a select using pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the issue with the obvious approach: `<option>` elements support `:checked`, but adjacency selectors (`a + b`, `a ~ b`) do not support matching subsequent elements unless they are in the same parent, therefore this cannot be used.

*However*, checkboxes and radiobuttons can be in a different container from their label, which can be utilized for plenty of "state" situations inside CSS - we just need to stitch together some sort of fake `<select>` with labels inside it, and put their `<input>`s outside, and then we can match via `~` as usual!

```css
body {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
}

/* a slightly janky custom dropdown */
.select {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* it's a flexbox purely so that we can use `order` on the active element to move it to the top of the list */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* restyle labels to look vaguely like options */
.select label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  background: white;
}

/* hide labels in out-of-focus dropdowns [except the active one] */
.select:not(:focus) label {
  display: none;
  /* this is to prevent clicking the current item instead of activating the dropdown */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* this is to override background from the multi-rule below */
  background: white!important;
}

.select:focus label {
  z-index: 100;
  /* and then allow clicking them once it actually has focus */
  pointer-events: all;
}

.select:focus label:hover {
  background: #08f!important; /* ditto */
  color: white;
}

/*
here's the catch: you can't just display:none the radiobuttons,
as then your dropdown will not lose focus and thus will not
close upon changing the active item.
So we just move them somewhere far away
*/
input.option {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999999px;
}

/*
this allows the correct label to be shown inside
a dropdown when it is not open.
please don't write these by hand
*/
#s1_1:checked ~ .select label[for="s1_1"],
#s1_2:checked ~ .select label[for="s1_2"],
#s1_3:checked ~ .select label[for="s1_3"],
#s2_1:checked ~ .select label[for="s2_1"],
#s2_2:checked ~ .select label[for="s2_2"]{
  display: block;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  /*
  makes the selected element show up on the top of the options list, 
  otherwise it's a bit disorienting
  */
  order: -1;
}

/* and finally, the actual selector */
#s1_2:not(:checked) ~ #s2 { display: none };
```

```html
<input class="option" type="radio" name="s1" id="s1_1" checked/>
<input class="option" type="radio" name="s1" id="s1_2"/>
<input class="option" type="radio" name="s1" id="s1_3"/>
<div class="select" tabindex="1">
  <label for="s1_1">Option 1</label>
  <label for="s1_2">Option 2 [!]</label>
  <label for="s1_3">Option 3</label>
</div>
Some text after
<input class="option" type="radio" name="s2" id="s2_1" checked/>
<input class="option" type="radio" name="s2" id="s2_2"/>
<div class="select" tabindex="2" id="s2">
  <label for="s2_1">Option 1</label>
  <label for="s2_2">Option 2</label>
</div>
```